# How to install groovy-desktop-full on 12.04

Tags: ros-groovy

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all,
I have problems installing groovy on my machine. I currently have fuerte installed. Without fuerte, it is the same situation. Is this a known situation?

```
sudo apt-get install ros-groovy-desktop-full 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 ros-groovy-desktop-full : Depends: ros-groovy-ros-tutorials (= 0.3.9-0precise-20121230-1218-+0000) but it is not going to be installed
                           Depends: ros-groovy-navigation-tutorials (= 0.1.1-s1357276030~precise) but it is not going to be installed
                           Depends: ros-groovy-geometry-tutorials (= 0.1.3-s1357177371~precise) but it is not going to be installed
                           Depends: ros-groovy-slam-gmapping (= 1.2.7-s1357273397~precise) but it is not going to be installed
                           Depends: ros-groovy-vision-opencv (= 1.10.0-0precise-20130103-2233-+0000) but it is not going to be installed
                           Depends: ros-groovy-perception-pcl (= 1.0.25-0precise-20130104-0111-+0000) but it is not going to be installed
                           Depends: ros-groovy-rqt-common-plugins (= 0.2.7-0precise-20130104-0046-+0000) but it is not going to be installed
                           Depends: ros-groovy-image-pipeline (= 1.10.1-0precise-20130104-0139-+0000) but it is not going to be installed
                           Depends: ros-groovy-rqt-robot-plugins (= 0.2.7-0precise-20130103-2333-+0000) but it is not going to be installed
                           Depends: ros-groovy-common-tutorials (= 0.2.3-s1357260899~precise) but it is not going to be installed
                           Depends: ros-groovy-image-transport-plugins (= 1.8.15-0precise-20130104-0046-+0000) but it is not going to be installed
                           Depends: ros-groovy-visualization-tutorials (= 0.7.3-s1357254450~precise) but it is not going to be installed
                           Depends: ros-groovy-laser-pipeline (= 1.5.5-s1357268665~precise) but it is not going to be installed
                           Depends: ros-groovy-simulator-gazebo (= 1.7.6-s1357263540~precise) but it is not going to be installed
                           Depends: ros-groovy-rviz (= 1.9.18-0precise-20130103-2233-+0000) but it is not going to be installed
                           Depends: ros-groovy-navigation (= 1.10.1-s1357270099~precise) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/52155/how-to-install-groovy-desktop-full-on-12.04/) by [aswin](https://answers.ros.org/users/212/aswin/) on ROS Answers with karma: 528 on 2013-01-13

Post score: 3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

u can try this:

```
sudo apt-get purge ^ros*
sudo apt-get autoclean
```

these two commands will remove all the old version of ros.
then install groovy according to the tutorial.
Of course, reinstall ubuntu and install groovy is the last thing u can do~
good luck

---

Originally posted by [Kent](https://answers.ros.org/users/3533/kent/) with karma: 140 on 2013-01-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [aswin](https://answers.ros.org/users/212/aswin/) on 2013-01-19**:
It helped remove fuerte, but did not solve the problem. The trouble maker was qt. For some reason, qt was affecting install of some packages in groovy. After removal of qt, it was fine